# upload a file and save to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am a newbie programmer and I'm not really good in English. I will ask a question about my code. I'm getting confused when I input an image and save it to database in `phpmyadmin`. The noimage.jpg is displayed even when I input another file. Please help me solve the problem. Thankyou

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
else {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
        $config['allowed_types'] ='gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] ='2048';
        $config['max_width'] ='500';
        $config['max_height'] ='500';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
           $error = array(
               'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
            );
           $post_image ='noimage.jpg';

        }
        else {
           //if uploaded        
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image= $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }
        $this->post_model->create_post($post_image);           
        redirect('posts');
}
```

Comment: the issue occurs due to a wrong upload path. Could you `var_dump($error) ` and let check issue.

Comment: Make sure your form is multi-part and dump the  request data even before validating

Comment: make sure the uploaded file types is gif, jpg and png. otherwise $ post_image always returns the value is noimage.jpg. because allowed of types only  gif, jpg and png, other than that considered error